# Sending Large or Complex Objects from WCF server to clients

Tags: wcf, real-time, wcf-binding, buffering, large-data-volumes

My application is near real time data buffering application.

I,m using net. TCP bindings to send complex objects.

buffering data through different call-back functions to the client.

as much as i enable certain events the application slow down and converted to be none real time.

any one can help to the optimal way to make real time data buffering to multiple clients with large complex objects in WCF ???

Comment: Did you profile your app? Is CPU 100% busy and what eats most of it? Which serializer is used? Is server-type GC enabled? Is available network bandwidth sufficient?